# Need help in finding Xpath for a table element

Tags: selenium, xpath

[Image of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QerO.png)

WebElement htmltable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'table1')]"));

```
List<WebElement>  rows = htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
System.out.println("Number of rows:"+rows.size());

for(int rnum=0;rnum<rows.size();rnum++)
{
    List<WebElement> columns=rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    System.out.println("Number of columns:"+columns.size());

    for(int cnum=0;cnum<columns.size();cnum++)
    {
           WebElement calenderElement = columns.get(cnum);
           System.out.println(calenderElement.getText());

          WebElement Pmdate = calenderElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'+odd+')]"));
          System.out.print(Pmdate.getText());



    }
```

I'm new to selenium and got struct in selecting div element of the table. Could anyone please help me in solving this.

Comment: Attached the image of the html code

Comment: What is the error, or what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Never use images for code, XML, or HTML -- always text formatted as code.

Comment: I should be able to click calendar element.  Code looks like below.
<table id ="table1">

Comment: I cannot add complete code. Can you please check the screenshot for an idea. I should be able to click the Div element  under <td>.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the keyword 'odd' in the DIV element. But from the screenshot (PLEASE NEVER POST SCREENSHOTS, POST THE CODE!!!) I can only see 'odd' in the 'class' attribute of the DIV element. So maybe you want to change your XPath to

```
//*[contains(@class,'odd')]
```